# how do I add a circular border to table in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I am new to table widget and I read the documentation but I couldn't find a way to make the table border slightly curved , so is there something I am missing ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Wrap your table with a container and remove table border if any:

```
Container(
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(
      width: 1,
    ),
    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10)),
  ),
)
```

If you need to display the inner borders:

```
Table(
  border: TableBorder.symmetric(
    inside: BorderSide(width: 1),
  ),
)
```

Comment: thanks , but I need a separator between each cell and column not only outline border

Comment: You can still use the inner border, I'll update the answer for this.

Comment: How do I add additional padding for top and bottom on dynamic content? The rounded corners cut into cells

Comment: @AntonDuzenko you can use the `padding` property in the `Container`.

Answer (score 0):

**Update [2024]:**

For someone still looking for the updated answer

```
DataTable(
        border: TableBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20)),
        . . .
```